# Get Bulk AAD User Objects / Directory Object from List of UPN submitted to Graph API

Tags: graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have requirement to validate Object ID/UPN in request payload. We are planning to make use of below URL to get Directory Object ID. Is it right way to validate User/Group/Service Principal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

We call our Partner Service, who returns list of UPNs. Is there any Graph API similar to "GetByIds" to retrieve User Objects/ Directory Objects from the list of UPN. Instead of iterating individual UPN and call Graph API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no method to retrieve User Objects/ Directory Objects from the list of UPN in the Graph API

You can use PowerShell to get the list of Object IDs from the list of UPN by using the below command:

```
$result |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId  $_.UserPrincipalName
    } | select ObjectId
```

[image]

**Note**: The variable $result contains the list of UPN

Now, you can use "GetByIds" to retrieve User Objects / Directory Objects from the list of Object IDs in the Graph API

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Currently, this is no such API that exists today.

Being said that, consider filing [Uservoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so it could be considered for future implementations.

Thanks.